# LIBGDX - SetScreen nullpointer Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, libgdx

i'm actually having a problem with libgdx.

TypingGame.java

```
public class TypingGame extends Game {

TypingGame game;

GameScreen gameScreen;
GameOverScreen gameOverScreen;

@Override
public void create() {      

    gameScreen = new GameScreen();
    gameOverScreen = new GameOverScreen(game);

    Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false);
    setScreen(new GameScreen()); // Default screen : Gamescreen

}


}
```

I'd like to be able to change the current screen by using setScreen. Here's what I did :

GameScreen.java

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor{

private World world;
private WorldRenderer renderer;
private WorldController controller;
TypingGame game;


@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Timer.elapsedTime(delta);
    renderer.render(delta);
    controller.update(delta);


    if(Player.health == 0) game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game)); // If the player died, switch to GameOverScreen
}

// And so on...
```

GameOverScreen.java

```
public class GameOverScreen implements Screen{


TypingGame game;
GameScreen gameScreen;

public GameOverScreen(TypingGame game){
    this.game = game;
    gameScreen = new GameScreen();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {


    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {


}

@Override
public void show() {


}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
```

}

I can't figure out why I have this error :

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This should be quite easy to use, but the only class where I can actually use setScreen is... TypingGame.java.

Your help would be much appreciated, thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Cya !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your TypingGame class you don't create a new instance of itself:

```
TypingGame game; //------------------ this!
...
gameOverScreen = new GameOverScreen(game); //----you don't pass the new "game", you pass "this"
```

also you have to do the same to GameScreen.

```
gameScreen = new GameScreen(this); //---like this
```

You are getting a NPE because in GameScreen you are trying to use a Game that does not exist. You need to pass the instance of TypingGame using "this" to your GameScreen,and store it in the:

```
TypingGame game;
```

of your GameScreen.

Also as a side note (but very important!),you are creating an instance of GameScreen and an instance of GameOverScreen but then every time you set a screen you create a new one...

Answer (score 0):

Also, why create a new `gameScreen` and then not use it in `setScreen()`?

```
gameScreen = new GameScreen();
gameOverScreen = new GameOverScreen(game);

Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false);
setScreen(new GameScreen()); // Default screen : Gamescreen
```

I would expect that last line to read: `setScreen(gameScreen);`